# Update document - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, collections, mongodb-query

> I want to update certain document, but I don't know how to access the
> spesific object.
>
> as you can see in the json file-

```
{
"screen": "screen-1",
"commeracials": [{
    **"id": 1**,
    "img": "./Hanukkah.jpg",
    "imgUrl": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/0IqiRIsplOA/maxresdefault.jpg",
    "duration": 1000
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "img": "./RoshHashanah.jpg",
    "imgUrl": "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/99/b0/7a/99b07ac3aa6483343346c17b4cfe87ff.jpg",
    "duration": 2000
}]
```

}

> I'm trying to access to an object inside an array by Id.
>
> I tried :

```
 ` 
        db
          .collection(collectionName)
          .updateMany(
            { screen: client.screen, commeracials: { id: commId } },
            {
              $set: { commeracials: client.commercials },
            }
          )
          .then((result) => {
            if (result.matchedCount=== 1) {
              console.log("Successfully updated one document.");
            } else {
              console.log(
                "No documents matched the query. Updated 0 documents."
              );
            }
          });
      })`
```

> but it does not work ( all the parametes are right). I get that
> result.matchedCount is 0... What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Please don't post your data in an image. Instead, post as valid json document so we can easier reproduce your issue and help.

Comment: @ray I changed it to document.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) to access the object property, otherwise you are matching the entire object.

Check [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ezr1fLl7gdA) how the `find` query does not find anything but removing `other` field and letting the last object in the array with only `id: 1` it can found ([example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3tHWx8EVF0t)).

This is because the query is comparing the whole object as you are used `commeracials: { id: commId }`

So using dot notation you can try this query:

```
db.collection.update({
  "screen": client.screen,
  "commeracials.id": commId 
},
{
  $set: {
    "commeracials.$": client.commercials
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Kk9tXT4FtAg)

Also note this query uses [positional operator (`$`)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) and the update set the entire object. If you only want to update one field you can use something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4VsNw4c4Qxt).

Also, as an append, take care to use the whole object to find a document. Check the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/) into section **Match an Embedded/Nested Document**:

> Equality matches on the whole embedded document require an exact match of the specified  document, including the field order.

[This example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SdnwMQOksGL) does not works while [this one](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1Qkp-Avo2cx), which is almost the same, works.

So, use dot notation, is safer.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It works :)